# How to call second controller from first controller only after certain function in controller one executed in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to communicate between two different controllers in AngularJs. The goal I want to achieve is to use the value of variable in first controller once is selected by drop down by user not the default value which i set. but   unfortunately second controller used the default value of variable in second controller.

I am so novice in Angular so forgive me if you think it's not properly represented I am from data science background.
here is the code i am using

```
<script>

    var app = angular.module("BuildApp", []);
    app.run(function ($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.$on('scope.stored', function (event, data) {
            console.log("scope.stored", data);
        });
    });

    app.controller("BranchController", function ($scope, $http, Scopes) {
        Scopes.store('BranchController', $scope);
        $http.get('http://192.168.3.96:8082/engine-api/1.1/builds/getbranch').
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.branchs = data;
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('Api call failed', status)
        });

        $scope.selectedBranch = 'Nothing Selected';
        $scope.dropboxitemselectedbranch = function (item) {
            $scope.selectedBranch  = item;
        }
    });

    app.controller("KitController", function ($scope, $http, Scopes) {
        Scopes.store('KitController', $scope);
        var url = 'http://192.168.3.96:8082/engine-api/1.1/builds/getkit?Branch=' + Scopes.get("BranchController").selectedBranch;
        console.log(url)
        $http.get(url).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.kits = data;
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('Api call failed', status)
        });
        $scope.selectedKit = "Nothing Selected";
        $scope.dropboxitemselectedkit = function (item) {
            $scope.selectedKit = item;
        }
    });

    app.factory('Scopes', function ($rootScope) {
        var mem = {};

        return {
            store: function (key, value) {
                mem[key] = value;
            },
            get: function (key) {
                return mem[key];
            }
        };
    });
</script>
```

and the Html look like following

```
<body ng-app="BuildApp">
<h1>Branch</h1>
<div  ng-controller="BranchController">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"> {{selectedBranch}}
            <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" >
            <li ng-repeat="branch in branchs"><branch ng-click = "dropboxitemselectedbranch(branch.name)"> {{branch.name}} </branch></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<h1>Kit</h1>

<div  ng-controller="KitController">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"> {{selectedKit}}
            <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2" >
            <li ng-repeat="kit in kits"><kit ng-click = "dropboxitemselectedkit(kit.name)">{{kit.name}}</kit></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

//controllers declaration
app.controller('myCtrl1',function($scope, $rootScope){
    $scope.selectedOption = "option-1";
    $scope.change = function() {
      $rootScope.$emit('changeName',{selectedOption:$scope.selectedOption});
    }
});

app.controller('myCtrl2',function($scope, $rootScope){
    $scope.selectedOption = "option-2";
    $rootScope.$on('changeName', function(event,data) {
      $scope.selectedOption = data.selectedOption;
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp"> 

<span class="div1" ng-controller="myCtrl1"> 
    <select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-change="change()">
      <option value="option-1">Option 1</option> 
      <option value="option-2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="option-3">Option 3</option>
      <option value="option-4">Option 4</option>
      <option value="option-5">Option 5</option>
    </select>
</span> 

<span class="div2" ng-controller="myCtrl2"> 
    <select ng-model="selectedOption">
      <option value="option-1">Option 1</option> 
      <option value="option-2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="option-3">Option 3</option>
      <option value="option-4">Option 4</option>
      <option value="option-5">Option 5</option>
    </select>
</span> 
 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use controllerAs to avoid bugs.
You should create third controller, and bind data to it or rewrite it in component architecture.

```
<div ng-controller="Parent as parent">
   <div ng-controller="Child1 as c1">
        <button ng-click="parent.myData = c1.doInterestingMagic()" ></button>

   </div>
   <div ng-controller="Child2 as c2">
        <span ng-bind="parent.myData || c2.defaultMyData"></span>
   </div>

</div>
```